# How to configure python's logging module to use the formatter for multiline output?

Tags: python

I've configured the logging module to format log messages with:

```
...
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] '
                      '(%(name)s:pid=%(process)d) %(module)s(%(lineno)d): '
                      '%(message)s'
        },
    },
...
```

However, when it prints an exception, it shows up like:

```
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105): Catchall exception at top level.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/argh/dispatching.py", line 228, in dispatch_command
    dispatch(parser, *args, **kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/argh/dispatching.py", line 124, in dispatch
    for line in lines:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/argh/dispatching.py", line 200, in _execute_command
    for line in result:
  ...,
NameError: global name 'sftp' is not defined
```

Is it possible to make it run each line through the formatter? E.g. so it would output something like:

```
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105): Catchall exception at top level.
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105): Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/argh/dispatching.py", line 228, in dispatch_command
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):     dispatch(parser, *args, **kwargs)
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/argh/dispatching.py", line 124, in dispatch
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):     for line in lines:
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/argh/dispatching.py", line 200, in _execute_command
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):     for line in result:
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105):   ...,
2014-02-12 14:16:20,454 [ERROR] (app:pid=1930) main(105): NameError: global name 'sftp' is not defined
```

Comment: Kind of... you would have to capture the exception string, split it on new lines and then log each line using your logger. However, this is not common practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without configuration. Use [`traceback.format_exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) to get the stack trace as a string, then split the lines and log each line individually.

```
import logging
import traceback

logger = logging.Logger(__name__) # or whatever namespace you so please
# do any other Logger configuration you want

try:
    do_some_stuff()
except Exception as e:
    for line in traceback.format_exec().split('\n'):
        logger.error(line)
```

This is not common practice, however. If you use [`Logger.exception()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) you could log the exception. It would be on one logging line, but it would be written on multiple lines to the file-like object to which the `Logger` is writing.

(Of interest is the fact that the `logging.Formatter` class' method, [`formatException`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException), uses `traceback.print_exception` for its default implementation.)

Comment: I'm currently using logger.exception() and that's the problem - multiple lines that aren't formatted.

Comment: @jbrown So, I've told you how you can accomplish this, but you should know that error logs aren't always read by humans. Typically, each logging message contains a timestamp to indicate when some sort of event occurred. When you do this, you are separating this one event into several events... do you get what I'm saying?

Answer (score -4):

I think you can use json module for that

```
import json

a = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

print json.dumps(a, indent=4)
```

output:

```
{
    "a": 1, 
    "b": 2
}
```

Comment: This is not using the logging module.

Comment: yes, but as I remember there is no such an option in logging directly

Comment: Actually this doesn't do what OP wanted at all, he wants the exception logged line-by-line. What you saw as JSON was actually YAML configuring the `Formatter` for the `Logger`.